# Ajax button with no OnClick event is causing a postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am completely new to Ajax and have had no training. I'm just copying a co-worker's code. We have a page with two Ajax controls: one my co-worker wrote and one I wrote. Everything is working fine except for one item, and my co-worker's up to his eyeballs in another project, so I need to figure this out. The problem is that the Ajax control I wrote pops up a ListBox with two buttons: Close and Select. The Select button has an OnClick event and causes a postback, as is expected. However, the Close button does *not* have an OnClick event and still causes a postback. This is not the case with a very similar Ajax control that my co-worker wrote that sits on the same page. The code is below. My co-worker's code involves the Email Template; mine involves the Email(s) Lookup. For the life of me, I don't see any difference. Can anyone tell me why my Close button causes a PostBack and my co-worker's doesn't?

```
<!--my co-worker's control-->
<tr>
        <td width="20%"><br /><div class="formtext">Email Template:</div></td>

 <td colspan="3"><br />
     <asp:Button ID="btn_ShowTemplate" runat="server" 
         Text="View/Edit Template"  />
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpTemplate" runat="server" PopupControlID="panelTemplate" TargetControlID="btn_ShowTemplate"
    CancelControlID="BtnTemplateClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

 <asp:Panel ID="panelTemplate" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupTemplate" align="center">
          <div class="formtext_modal">Litigation Hold Email Template <img src="images/v2/modal_email.png" alt="Email" /><br /></div>
          <cc1:Editor ID="TemplateEditor" runat="server" Width="675px" Height="400px" />
          <br />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnTemplateClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btnMatterClose" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnTemplateSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btnMatterSelect" OnClick="btnTemplateSave_Click" />
</asp:Panel></td>
  </tr>

<!--my control-->
<tr>
  <!-- email cc section -->
   <td>Email CC:<br /></td>
  <td colspan="3"><asp:Button ID="btnEmails" runat="server" Text="Lookup Email" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox 
          ID="tbEmails" runat="server" Width="80%" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox><br />
  <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpEmails" runat="server" PopupControlID="panelEmails" TargetControlID="btnEmails"
    CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="panelEmails" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupAttorneys" align="center">
     <table align="center" width="100%">
     <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="formtext_modal">Email(s) Lookup <img src="images/v2/modal_search.png" alt="Search" /></div><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Width="600px" CssClass="formtext" 
                Text="Add Employees to Email CC line"></asp:Label>
           <div  style="BORDER: thin solid; OVERFLOW: auto; WIDTH: 600px; HEIGHT: 140px">


              <asp:CheckBoxList  ID="cblEmails" runat="server" Width="600px" Height="140px"  SelectionMode="Multiple">
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>

       </td>  
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side buttons always cause a post back. One way to get around it is to add a client click function that returns false.

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

**Edit**

Your co-worker has defined the `CancelControlID="BtnTemplateClose"` on the `ModalPopupExtender`. That is what is repressing the post back. You also have the CancelControlID defined, but I can't find the close button (`btnClose`) anywhere in the code you have posted. Where are the close buttons in your control? If you make sure your close button has the ID `btnClose`, it would most likely work like your co-worker's close button.

Comment: But my co-worker's Close button does *not* cause a postback. I've verified this by putting a breakpoint on Page_Load and running the app through the debugger.

Comment: That was it, Jonas. I should've had btnEmailClose instead of btnClose. I probably renamed the button at some point and forgot to change the name after CancelControlID. Thank you!